# Appstore version crashes. Developer version doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm in kind of a pickle here...

A couple of weeks ago I released version 1.0.2 of my app. Apparently it had a bug when trying to add a contact in the app (local). When you pushed the add button, it would crash. I was baffled because in development and in beta we used this function constantly and never had something like this.

Not finding the bug but trying to rewrite parts of the function behing the add button, I released version 1.0.3 yesterday. It has the exact bug that crashes the app. This is making me crazy!

I tried figuring something out via iOS Console and this is the result when it crashes (it did this in both version 1.0.2 as 1.0.3):

[image: the crash]

The grayed out parts are the app's output.
Anybody got some information about this?

Comment: Could it be due to a jailbreak tweak that only affects AppStore apps? Try doing it in safe mode (I thought I saw a jailbreak tweak log in there, but I realize that you may not actually be jailbroken)

Comment: I've never jailbreaked this device nor wrote any code to prevent jailbreak entry... Thx anyway!

Comment: `unrecognized selector` crashes should happen everywhere.  So looks for instances where you call `row` and see how you could be sending it to the `UITouchEvent` class.  Could just be you haven't tested your app properly.

Comment: (Oh and to find out where it's crashing, simply symbolicate that stack trace starting with "First throw call stack:").

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't get your last comment. How do I do that stack trace?

Comment: An internet search will tell you.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know how to do it, but the problem is: there is no bug. Running it on the simulator, ipads, via TestFlight,... works just fine. Only when you download the app from the AppStore, it crashes. Any way to do a stack trace on those?

Comment: Do you know where it's happening?  The stack trace is in the bug report.  You need to symbolicate it from the archive you used to submit the app.  This is all documented by Apple and others, so go and read the documentation.

Comment: When I tap a button that starts a xib. But I have no idea why it would call Row. No rows there...

Comment: You are in denial.  You won't solve the issue until you get past that stage :)

Comment: Haha, you might be right ;) I'll give it a rest for a day and try to rewrite the whole stuff that has something to do with that button. Still don't understand why it only happens in the AppStore version...